# Использование XMLHttpRequest.readyState вне обработчиков

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) предлагает отслеживать загрузку XMLHttpRequest через события (progress, load, error и др.), в том числе через событие onreadystatechange, возникающее при изменении поля readyState.

Таким образом в обработчике onreadystatechange можно прочитать поле readyState и определить дальнейшие действия в зависимости от его значения.

Вопрос — можно ли использовать это поле (readyState) вне обработчиков событий XMLHttpRequest, например по таймеру или в обработчике клика мышки. Будет ли состояние этого поля в этом случае актуально? Или актуальность гарантируется только внутри вызовов обработчиков XMLHttpRequest?

Update

Такой же вопрос и касательно поля status (который показывает статус ответа на запрос, такой как 200, 404 и т.п.), если, к примеру, его значение равно 404 вне обработчиков событий XMLHttpRequest, можно ли это трактовать как неуспешный запрос?

Comment: а что не так с событиями?

Comment: @Grundy Ну во первых это просто кросиво, во вторых обработчик события нужно будет оставить в живых пока все события не отстреляются, в варианте периодического опроса можно просто забыть про существование более ненужного XMLHttpRequest запроса.

Comment: Ага :-) давайте нагрузим бесполезными циклами клиентские машины, а то они слишком быстро работают :)

Comment: @Grundy один черт под капотом таким же бесполезным циклом проверяется состояние закачки и вызывается обработчик события. Ну разве что нативным кодом.

Comment: Не таким же, нативный цикл может быть намного эффективнее цикла пропущенного через этапы работы виртуальной машины

Comment: @Grundy да понятн, щучю. Просто в моем случае tradеoff лишней проверки в цикле за счет снижения общей сложности вполне прокатывает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115961/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladimir-gamalyan).

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, можно.

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox?_="+Date.now();

let readyState = null, status = null;

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  // In local files, status is 0 upon success in Mozilla Firefox
  readyState = xhr.readyState;
   console.log('readyState', readyState);
  if(readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    status = xhr.status;
  }
};

let interval = setInterval(()=>{
  if(readyState){
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('status', status);
    console.log('data', xhr.responseText);
  }
}, 50);

xhr.send();
```

Comment: зачем делать `readyState = xhr.readyState;` если ты сразу можешь использовать `xhr.readyState`? и со статусом то же самое

Comment: Здесь фактически значение readyState выбирается внутри обработчика onreadystatechange, вопрос как раз в том, можно ли его использовать _вне_ обработчиков событий XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Данные поля расположены в объекте `XMLHttpRequest`, следовательно, обращаться к ним можно отовсюду, где доступен конкретный объект, в данном случае `xhr`.

Обработчики событий просто позволяют поймать конкретный момент, в который меняются значения полей.

Comment: У меня вроде как получается если подряд читать XMLHttpRequest.status (не в обработчике) то проскакивает 404, а затем уже 200 (для POST запроса, с preflight)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, так никто не гарантирует, что до изменения состояния будет корректное значение.

Comment: Читаю status когда readyState равно 4, т.е. вроде как выполнен запрос. Или корректное состояние гарантируется только после того как событие сработало? (в этом и вопрос, можно ли напрямую поллить поля, или в любом случае надо обработчики ставить)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, это может зависеть от браузера, в хроме например при запросе в stackoverflow, все консистентно. Попробуй привести пример, что именно ты делаешь и какой результат получаешь